# Ksh date validation YYYYMMDD

Tags: shell, scripting, ksh

I'm having a weird problem with the below simple date validation. 
It fails validation for some dates. 
An example is: 20140717

Other dates pass validation ok? i.e: 20140727

```
validate_date()
{

typeset my_date=$1

if [[ $my_date = [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]]  ; then
return 0;
else
return 1
fi
}
```

Can someone run it on ksh and see if the same happens?

Comment: It works for me, and you can reduce the function greatly to `validate_date () { [[ $1 = [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]]; }`

Comment: Thanks chepner. That was actually a sumplification of anotjer function with which i had the same problem with the same date :o.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me for some dates. Could there be an issue with putty caching previous tests ?

Comment: Very unlikely to be caching.  Try setting the -x flag and see what $my_date expands to.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see why the code is given improper result for your input .

I think one of the better ways of validating for date would be to use `date -d "datestring"`
it return the time displayed by the string in case of success and error in case date validation fails 
so after `date -d "datestring"` .. you can check the value of $? so know success or failure of validation .

for example

```
ajay@pavilion:~$ date -d 20140730
Wed Jul 30 00:00:00 IST 2014
ajay@pavilion:~$ echo $?
0
ajay@pavilion:~$ date -d 20140750
date: invalid date ‘20140750’
ajay@pavilion:~$ echo $?
1
ajay@pavilion:~$
```

Comment: Thanks ajay but the -d option is not an option in ksh. This is solved anyways, i changed the sintax to only use "-eq, -lt..." etc and it worked just fine. Thanks everyone!!

Comment: @sergiopuy date -d option is available with ksh93 .